# Is Harihara abheda mentioned in Smritis like Manu Smriti?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, manu-smriti, smriti, smarta

Is Harihara abheda (non-difference of Vishnu and Shiva) mentioned in the Smritis like Manusmriti or any other 17 Smritis?

Comment: Smrithi seems to expound on topics like code of conduct , dharma , administration etc,thereby it may be improbable to seek a reference on Hari Hara Abedha in smrithis.Many Puranaas,Prakarana granthas do contain the references of the same.